# Problem sending mail with Apache Commons email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

I'm trying to send a simple text email using [commons email](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html)

```
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("user@gmail.com", "123456"));
    email.setTLS(true);
    email.setFrom(from);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setMsg(mesage);
    email.addTo("to@gmail.com");
    email.send();
```

But when I try to send the email ,I get this exception:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need the [JavaMail API JAR](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-139225.html) as well (this is the `javax.mail` package).

Commons Email sits on top of the JavaMail API and makes it a little less awful to use.

Comment: You'll probably also need `activation.jar`, but I may remember it wrong.

Comment: @skaffman- thnx I only needed JavaMail API JAR, but I'm courious about activation.jar, when would I  need to use it??

Comment: @eddy: The Java Activation Framework handles MIME-related stuff in JavaMail. If you don't need it, all the better.

Comment: javax.activation is now standard in the 1.6 JRE.  In previous versions, you needed to include `activation.jar` in your classpath.